# ThreeJS mesh does not appear after adding it to scene then positioning the camera to fill its view

Tags: three.js

In this bit of code an .obj model is loaded into the scene then the camera's z position is moved to a point where the mesh's bounding box fills the view.

The problem is that the mesh does not appear unless I manually fiddle with the orbit controls or if I comment out the camera.position.z line.

Is there a way to force the camera to render or otherwise force the mesh to appear?

```
function loadModel() {
    mesh.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child.isMesh ) child.material.map = texture;
    } );

    var geometry = mesh.children[0].geometry;
    geometry.center();

    mesh.scale.copy(new THREE.Vector3(100,100,100));

    scene.add( mesh );

    var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( mesh );
    var object3DWidth  = box.max.x - box.min.x;
    var object3DHeight = box.max.y - box.min.y;
    var object3DDepth  = box.max.z - box.min.z;

    // position camera to fill view according to bounding box size
    var size=Math.max(object3DHeight,object3DWidth);
    var dist= size / 2 / Math.tan(Math.PI * cameraFov / 360); 

    camera.position.z = dist; 
 //// if I remove the line above the mesh will appear but not zoomed ////
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to reproduce the issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)? It will be easier to provide help if you provide an opportunity for debugging.

Comment: I've created a fiddle that loads a cube mesh then zooms the camera. It seems to work as I want. Not sure how to load and test an .obj model instead though.  https://jsfiddle.net/hfeist/mf1o8c0u/

Comment: Here is fiddle with `three.js` and `OBJLoader`. It already loads an OBJ file from the `three.js` repository. Maybe this helps you to reproduce your issue. https://jsfiddle.net/j2agonrz/

Comment: Thank you for your help. Very generous. It seems the problem doesn't occur inside fiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/hfeist/e2kpo36g/ I tried using a link to the .obj on my server but that seems not to be allowed for security reasons.

Comment: Here's a link to the problem. Once the page is loaded you need to click/drag the mouse to make the mesh show up.   http://www.haroldfeist.com/TEST/moonrocks/centeredMoved.php

Comment: 2 possibilities off the top of my head. One, your `far` setting on your camera is too small so the object doesn't fit. Two, the object is above or below. I ran into this issue [here](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-load-obj.html) so you can try out similar solutions

Comment: @user2016210 `camera.position.z = - dist;` This is something you should have been able to debug yourself.

Comment: You make a very good point as well as solving the problem.